# É possível avaliar uma expressão ternária com 3 valores possíveis?

Tags: c#, estilo-de-codificação, condição

Digamos que eu tenha essa conta:

```
var total = valor1 / valor2;
```

O resultado poderia ser três valores possíveis, tipo:

- total > 5
- total > 0 e total < 5
- um valor positivo

Obs.: São valores percentuais, logo 5% é igual a 0,05.

Poderia usar um `if` que testasse tudo, mas a pergunta é: semelhante a um operador ternário, é possível?

Comment: Em realidade eu preciso pintar um BoxView dependendo do resultado. Tentei isso, mas não consigo colocar o boxview para pintar.

Comment: Qualquer solução proposta vai ter que seguir um dos 3 caminhos possível. E que eu saiba não tem como fazer de uma forma simplificada. O mais provável é que se encapsule em um método.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Não. O operador ternário só trabalha com duas expressões.

O máximo que você pode fazer é algo parecido com o código abaixo, aninhando os ternários.

Tenha em mente que isso deixa o código extremamente difícil de ler.

```
var resultado = total < 5 ? 
                  ((total > 0) ? "Menor que cinco, mas maior que zero" 
                               : "Menor que cinco, zero ou menos") 
                : "Maior ou igual a cinco";
```

<sup>[**Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bA70wo)</sup>

---

**Edição**

Como eu sei que você é um admirador de expressões, lambdas, funções e etc. E também lembro de uma pergunta que você apagou onde perguntava algo como evitar um monte de if's usando expressões, eu decidi escrever um código com isso adaptado ao problema atual.

Tenha em mente que esta não é uma solução concreta dadas as circunstâncias, você pode sim tirar proveito deste código, mas eu acredito que não para o problema atual.

Explicação: O código basicamente se baseia numa lista de pares de chave-valor, onde cada elemento desta lista tem como chave uma expressão que toma como entrada (parâmetro) um número decimal e retorna um `boolean` (**`Func<decimal, bool>`**). Os valores destes pares são uma *string* descritiva com o resultado, obviamente isso pode ser trocado para qualquer coisa, mas eu decidi deixar assim para ficar mais ilustrativo.

O método **`ValidarTotal`** itera sobre todos estes itens, faz a chamada da função (que é a **chave** do par) passando o parâmetro `valor` como entrada da função e, se o resultado for `true`, retorna o **valor** do par. Obviamente é possível alterar para que isso seja agrupado, eu fiz isto no método `ValidarTotalAgrupado`. A ideia dele é a mesma do primeiro, com a diferença que irá retornar uma *string* com todos os valores onde a função retornou `true` e que eu usei LINQ.

Código:

```
KeyValuePair<Func<decimal, bool>, string>[] pares = new[]   
{
    new KeyValuePair<Func<decimal, bool>, string>(valor => valor > 5, "Maior que 5"),
    new KeyValuePair<Func<decimal, bool>, string>(valor => valor > 0 && valor < 5, "Maior que 0 e menor que 5"),
    new KeyValuePair<Func<decimal, bool>, string>(valor => valor > 0, "Número positivo")
};

static string ValidarTotalAgrupado(decimal valor, params KeyValuePair<Func<decimal, bool>, string>[] pares)
{
    var ret = pares.Where(p => p.Key(valor))
                   .Select(p => p.Value)
                   .Aggregate((a, b) => $"{a}, {b}");

    return ret;
}

static string ValidarTotal(decimal valor, params KeyValuePair<Func<decimal, bool>, string>[] pares)
{
    foreach(var item in pares)
    {
        if(item.Key(valor)) {
            return item.Value;
        }
    }   
    return null;
}

void Main()
{   
    var testes = new[] 
    {
        new { Valor = 6m },
        new { Valor = 2m },
        new { Valor = 0.5m }
    };

    foreach(var teste in testes)
    {
        var res = ValidarTotal(teste.Valor, pares);
        var resAgrupado = ValidarTotalAgrupado(teste.Valor, pares);

        Console.WriteLine($"Valor: {teste.Valor:n2}\nResultado: {res}\nAgrupado: {resAgrupado}\n");
    }
}
```

<sup>[**Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle.**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yKEGEQ)</sup>

Comment: Sim, como disse cai na mesma do if, talvez o if seja mais limpo paraler.

Comment: @pnet Fiz uma edição que eu acho que você vai achar legal.

Comment: Linq, não testei aqui comigo porque tive que me focar em terminar um layout do App que estou desenvolvendo, mas vou testar. Vou marcar a resposta, pois no Fiddle funcionou e acho que vai funcionar comigo. Qualquer coi, voltamos e postamos, mas acho que resolve sim. Apaguei aquele post, pois não estava fazendo sentido a forma da pergunta e ia receber down e como não havia resposta apaguei. Sim sou fão da lambda e odeio IF's, rs.

Comment: @pnet Tranquilo, não esqueça de ler o corpo da resposta, tem considerações importantes

Answer (score 10):

É possível usar operadores condicionais aninhados, mas é desencorajado por diminuir a legibilidade, ainda que dê para ajudar um pouco:

```
resultado = total > 5 ? 5 :
            total < 5 ? 1 :
            total > 0 ? 0;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Operator/ConditionalNested.cs).

Comment: Cai na mesma do **IF**, já que o objetivo é melhorar a legibilidade.